# Is it possible to create or update the table given an array of arrays that represent the rows?

Tags: laravel, laravel-6

I am using Laravel 6.
I have an example array of arrays:

```
$data_arr = [
['id' =>'x', 'condition'=>'xx', 'col1' => 'col1_value', 'col2' => 'col2_value'],
['id' =>'y', 'condition'=>'yy', 'col1' => 'col1_value', 'col2' => 'col2_value'],
['id' =>'z', 'condition'=>'zz', 'col1' => 'col1_value', 'col2' => 'col2_value'],
// and so on
]
```

I want to update or create the rows in the table that match the `id` and `condition`. I currently use a `foreach` loop with Eloquent. I also filter out `id` and `condition` into the variables `$id` and `$condition` beforehand so it matches the `createOrUpdate` syntax:

```
foreach ($data_arr as $data) {
    $update_or_create = Model::updateOrCreate(
        ['id' => $id, 'condition' => $condition],
        $data
    );
}
```

Is it possible to simplify that? And maybe use single insert and not `foreach`?

Comment: You have the correct approach and syntax for Laravel 6. In later versions, there's the [`upsert()` method](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent#upserts), which would be `Model::upsert($data_arr, ['id', 'condition'])`

Comment: Upsert can only work if you have set your `id` and `condition` as unique and primary in the database structure. else keep using `updateOrCreate`

Answer (score 0):

There is a simple method for doing that without for loop . By using upsert() method :

```
Flight::upsert([
    ['departure' => 'Oakland', 'destination' => 'San Diego', 'price' => 99],
    ['departure' => 'Chicago', 'destination' => 'New York', 'price' => 150]
], ['departure', 'destination'], ['price']);
```

Instead of providing entire array content, you can simply use :

```
Flight::upsert($dataArray, ['id', 'condition']);
```

Reference : https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent#upserts

Comment: But not in Laravel 6 :(